# currentUser isn't null after calling Parse.User.logOut

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm trying to logout the currentUser when pressing a Actionbar button. This is the code I use:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_logout) {
        ParseUser.logOutInBackground(new LogOutCallback() {
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
                    if (currentUser == null) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(WelcomeActivity.this, DispatchActivity.class);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(WelcomeActivity.this, "Still logged in.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(WelcomeActivity.this, "Error msg:" + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

The problem is that when i press the button i get the message: `Still logged in.`. This means that`ParseUser.logOut` is called but `ParseUser.getCurrentUser()` isn't set to null. I do not get any messages in the Logcat regarding Parse.

The reason I need currentUser to be null, is because I use this bit of code to check if there is a user cached:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Check if there is current user info
    if (ParseUser.getCurrentUser() != null) {
        // Start an intent for the logged in activity
        startActivity(new Intent(this, WelcomeActivity.class));
    } else {
        // Start and intent for the logged out activity
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
    }
}
```

Why doesn't `ParseUser.getCurrentUser()` get set to null when calling `ParseUser.logOut`? Is there another solution to my problem?

I use version 1.10.3 of Parse.

EDIT:
To initialize Parse into my project i use an application file called `ParseApplication.java`.

```
public class ParseApplication extends Application{
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
        Parse.initialize(this, "1IwScbCSI157HcqFWCyR3qF8pqqGfNwPDoXnjyAd", "yIyVXPLM8h7V0ISGL3IxPaIqoUisK4w26EkWzs2W");
        ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
        ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
    }

}
```

The .java file is declared as the application in my `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application
        android:name=".ParseApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/app_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.parse.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="@string/parse_app_id" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.parse.CLIENT_KEY"
        android:value="@string/parse_client_key" />
```

EDIT2:

I did some research into my project and found out that i had accidentally declared `Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);` inside another .java file. I removed this from my file and now it works like a charm. This was the problem causing my app to crash.

Comment: Do you have Anonymous user feature enabled ?

Comment: I had it on, i turned it off but `ParseUser.getCurrentUser()` didn't get set to null. Just to clarify, you mean the settings for the app at Parse.com?

Comment: Could be an issue from having anonymous users at one point. It's possible there could be a cached anonymous user. Try deleting/reinstalling the app and see if the problem persists. Also, throw in the version of Parse you are using. This is probably a bug and should be reported

Comment: No I mean on the client. Enabling anonymous user feature means that your current user will never be null.

Comment: @MoNazemi, According to Parse API there is only a way to enable the anonymous user `enableAutomaticUser()`. @Russell, I've tried to delete and re-installing the application, but it doesn't seem to work. I've updated my answer with the Parse version. EDIT: I found that i use `ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();`. It's declared after `Parse.initialize(this)`. When i remove the line, the app crashes and i get this error message: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: `Parse#enableLocalDatastore(Context)` must be invoked before `Parse#initialize(Context)``.

Comment: Find the Parse.initialize function and put `Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);` before it

Comment: I've updated my answer with more information regarding parse initialization.

Comment: @MoNazemi I figured out the problem that caused the app to crash after removing `ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();`. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Why do you expect getCurrentUser() to return a null? Is there documentation that says it returns null after you've logged out?

Comment: @iheanyi Yes, there are documentation at Parse API stating that `getCurrentUser()` will return null after successfully calling `logOut()`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you subclassed ParseUser in the app? If yes, then try with that class. Also, if you have automatic user creation enabled then logging out and fetching user will return anonymous user. This is on by default.

Hope this helps you out.